# error: 'zmq' has not been declared

Tags: c++, build, compilation, declaration, zeromq

When building/compiling I am getting this error:

```
C:\Ethe\main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
C:\Ethe\main.cpp:11:4: error: 'zmq' has not been declared
C:\Ethe\main.cpp:11:19: error: expected ';' before 'context'
C:\Ethe\main.cpp:12:4: error: 'zmq' has not been declared
C:\Ethe\main.cpp:12:18: error: expected ';' before 'socket'
C:\Ethe\main.cpp:14:4: error: 'zmq' has not been declared
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <zmq.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
   std::string tip;
   std::cout << "Enter Target IP: ";
   std::cin >> tip;

   zmq::context_t context (1);
   zmq::socket_t socket (context, ZMQ_REQ);
   std::cout << "Connecting to " << tip << std::endl;
   zmq::socket.connect ("tcp://"+tip+":5555");

   return 0;
}
```

Anyone got any ideas on how i can fix this?

Comment: My guess is you need to have `#include "zmq.h"` instead of `#include <zmq.h>`

Comment: @DennisMeng I tried and that made no difference

Comment: In that case, where exactly is that header file?

Comment: @DennisMeng It's in my program files with the installation of zmq's source and its included libraries.

Comment: Are you sure `socket_t` and `context_t` are defined in `zmq.h`?

Comment: @RichieaaronMorris

In that case, the location of wherever that is could very well be the issue. When you do a `#include`, the compiler and linker don't automatically look through every possible folder; there are specific places where it'll look.

Comment: @olevegard This is the example I am using http://zguide.zeromq.org/cpp:hwclient

Comment: Is your compiler giving any errors about not being able to include zmq.h, or not being able to find it ? If not, it might be that you aren't including the library correctly.

Comment: The example says `zmq.hpp`, not `zmq.h` One of the answers below states this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add `#include <zmq.hpp>` This will include the C++ api of libzmq. However, in the zmq verions 2.x version it was included with the install, nowadays in the zmq-3.x.y version it is not shipped with the library anymore, as you can see from http://github.com/zeromq/zeromq3-x/raw/master/NEWS

The C++ api was excluded from the core library since the less is more strategy from zeromq. It is still downloadable from: https://github.com/zeromq/cppzmq/blob/master/zmq.hpp

This header is written around all C structures and functions the C API zeromq, therefore the entire C++ API is a single headerfile. Downloadable from the link above.

Answer (score 0):

If you wrote zmq.h by yourself, it should be `"zmq.h"`.